# stacking fullsized background images using bootstrap horizontally?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to stack 3 background images fully sized in the background using bootstrap in React. The images are wonky and have weird sizing and have whitespace between them.

I've tried messing with the image dimensions but it won't be responsive.

```
<div className="container">
    <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${CityLife})`, backgroundSize: '100% auto', minHeight: '100%', minHeight: '1000px', backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat' }}>
        Test2
    </div>
    <div  style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${GoodLife})`, backgroundSize: '100% auto', minHeight: '100%', minHeight: '1000px', backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat' }}>
        Test2
    </div>
</div>
```

It would be great if the pictures stacked up in full size on top of each other while being reponsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox is great for things like this.

You mentioned you need to use Bootstrap, which is fine, you can mix the two.

Flex properties to get it to work:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row // or 'column' for inline
}

.img {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 5%;
}

.img-1,
.img-2,
.img-3 {
  /* you can inherit some of these properties with another css class */
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000);
  display: block;
  padding: 4%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="img img-1"> one </div>
  <div class="img img-2"> two </div>
  <div class="img img-3"> three </div>
</div>
```